# Stripe pre-order checkout setup

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout, preorder

It's my first time using stripe. 
I try to use the stripe on one of my site doing pre-order check out, I checked stripe documentation of [checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) and [save card](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) information is not quite I looking for.

I was thinking set up for pre-order, people can click the button to check out first, but not get charged until Launch date.

And look like stripe checkout form element requires a backend server side.

My question is can Stripe work like click button for checkout, and charge when the launches day? Because the site I currently work on just plain HTML/CSS and Javascript only.

Thank you.

Here's the code I saw on stripe check out documentation:

```
<form action="your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_2MSNFrhPzEPgleHtFgxxxxxx"
data-amount="999"
data-name="sample"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-locale="auto">
 </script>
 </form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not something that is supported. Stripe requires a backend to process payments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! @Spiff